# How can I find out which ETFs has holdings in a particular stock?

Tags: stocks, etf

Instead of (or in addition to) investing in a particular stock, I'd like to research ETFs that has holdings in a particular stock, and possibly invest in those instead. Is there a central place or places that has this information, aside from the individual ETFs website?

Comment: Are you looking for ETFs that hold in a particular stock? Like HDV holds AT&T and many other stocks? I think BWMustang13 is using a different meaning for 'track'

Comment: Correct. I can see the confusion because strictly speaking the etf tracks an index, however with the latest boom of etfs a lot of indexes are home-grown and lesser known so to speak.

Comment: To avoid confusing people, you should rewrite your title: "How can I find out which ETF's hold a particular stock."  An ETF is a fund that holds assets (stocks) and tracks an index.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This ETFchannel.com page shows which ETFs hold [Wells Fargo](https://www.etfchannel.com/symbol/wfc/) and you can search other stocks the get the same information on that site.
This the same information for [Google](https://www.etfchannel.com/etfs/?symbol=Goog)

This even tells you what percentage of an ETF is a particular stock.

Be warned that this site is not entirely free. You will be limited to 6 pages in 6 hours unless you pay for a subscription.

Additionally [ETFdb.com](http://etfdb.com/tool/etf-stock-exposure-tool/) offers a similar tool.

Answer (score 1):

An ETF does not track any one individual stock. It "is a marketable security that tracks an index, a commodity, bonds, or a basket of assets like an index fund." Check out [this link](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/etf.asp) to learn more about ETFs. The easiest way see what ETF tracks a stock is to determine what sector and industry that company is in and find some ETF that trade it. The ETF will likely trade that stock, assuming that its market cap and exchange it trades on fits within the parameters of the ETF.

Comment: Thanks, but I know what an etf is, perhaps my language was confusing, see the comment on my question. The goal is: instead of researching an individual etf to see what holdings it has, I'd like to search a stock or group of stocks and find out what ETFs has holdings in that stock, and if so what percentages.